# Why does this pattern occur?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I first saw this pattern when I was trying to factor quadratics.

let $a + b = k$ where $k$ is any constant,

Now let $(a - b)/2 = x$

It appears to be that   $(k^2/4) - x^2 = a*b$

For example, let's say $k = 8$

then,

$4*4 = 16$

$3*5 = 15$

$2*6 = 12$

$1*7 = 7$

$0*8 = 0$

$-1*9 = -9$

If we subtract 16 from all of those, we get $0, -1, -4,-9, -16, and -25$.

My question is, why does this pattern occur? Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but there are so many variables that I don't know where to start

Comment: You also need to halve x; it works if $x=\frac{a-b}2$

Comment: Linear algebra is the wrong tag for this question as squares are not linear.  Precalculus would be a better tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the original post, $x=a-b$ and was changed to $x=\frac{a-b}{2}$.  This answer addresses both formulae.

Consider
$$
\frac{k^2}{4}-x^2=\frac{(a+b)^2}{4}-(a-b)^2=\frac{a^2}{4}+\frac{ab}{2}+\frac{b^2}{4}-a^2+2ab-b^2=-\frac{3}{4}a^2+\frac{5}{2}ab-\frac{3}{4}b^2=-\frac{3}{4}(a-b)^2+ab
$$
This is *not* $ab$, except in fairly special situations.

Now, if $x=\frac{a+b}{2}$ (as suggested in the comments and what appears to be the OP's original intent from the line starting with if we subtract 16...)
$$
\frac{k^2}{4}-x^2=\frac{(a+b)^2}{4}-\frac{(a-b)^2}{4}=\frac{a^2}{4}+\frac{ab}{2}+\frac{b^2}{4}-\frac{a^2}{4}+\frac{ab}{2}-\frac{b^2}{4}=ab,
$$
as desired.

This happens because $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$ and $(a-b)^2=a^2-2ab+b^2$.  Therefore, $(a+b)^2-(a-b)^2=4ab$, which can be scaled to $ab$.  Tricks like this often show up on calculus exams, especially in arc-length situations.